# Using Deno to Compile TypeScript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, deno

I'm working on some Deno projects and would like to be able to compile TypeScript to JavaScript to run in the browser (since TS is not yet supported). When I worked with NodeJS I installed the `tsc` compiler using npm but it seems overkill to install a second JavaScript runtime (NodeJS) just to get access to `tsc`. Does Deno have a compiler built-in?

I'm running Ubuntu server.

Comment: Installation doc here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/download

Comment: Thanks for the quick response however the link you posted suggests installing via npm which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [built in bundler](https://deno.land/manual/tools/bundler), so you don't need separate tool.

Answer (score 2):

As of Deno 1.31, the built in bundler is now deprecated. There is an official deno module for transpiling but sadly it is recommended that other modules/services are used.

I've created a deno package that tries to stay true to the original here:
https://github.com/jeff-hykin/deno_bundle